# Using <pre> and <code> tags to display a javascript script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pre

I'm experimenting with the < pre> and < code> tags in html 5 as I would like to include some code snippets on my website. I'm using the page below as a test page but it is not displaying anything. Any reason why?

```
    <body>
    <div style="color:#000000">
      <pre>
        <code>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#inputField').hide();
          </script>
        </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
    </body>
```

It was my understanding that using these new tags would negate any code that they contain within however this does not appear to be the case.

Cheers,

J

Comment: Remove the `<script>` anything within this will be interpreted and parsed as a script

Answer (score 32, accepted):

These tags are only for "decorational" purposes. Code within will still be executed. If you want it displayed you have to convert at least the `<script>` tag to html:

```
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;
```

Then the JavaScript code inbetween will be shown.

You don't need both though, I would use `<pre>` (which is per default a block element), `<code>` is intended for inline use.

Comment: According the site I read up on it about, you should wrap <code> tags with the <pre> tag.

Comment: It doesn't hurt, it just looks "wrong" ... at least to me, but that may be personal bias.

Comment: Just found [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742907/why-does-html5-recommend-putting-the-code-element-inside-pre) about `<code>` within `<pre>`.

Comment: Yeah. It's the white-spacing side of things that I think is the main issue here and that is why they should be used in conjunction (because I'm a bit ocd about maintaining my indents).

Answer (score 5):

Remove `script` tag:

```
<body>
    <div style="color:#000000">
      <pre>
        <code>
            $('#inputField').hide();
        </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I thought as much. That's why the javascript was creating a console error in Firebug.

Answer (score 3):

> It was my understanding that using these new tags would negate any code that they contain

They don't. They tell user agents to *present* the data as code. So it will have font changes, white space will be significant, it should be skipped over by translation software and so on.

Markup still takes effect (so you can add elements to style, or link the code to other places, and so on) so you still need to replace HTML special characters (`<`, `&`, etc) with their respective entities (`&lt;`, `&amp;`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

This would work if you take the **script** tags out.

These code tags only change the font of the text inside to a monospace font, however it does not override the interpretation of other tags (or even php tags).

A better way is to use CSS to get color highlighting, or javascript libraries.

Comment: I'm using these for semantic purposes. The <pre> tag also takes into account the whitespace so it's not just a case of changing the font like you mention above.

Comment: Oh yes they do. My note on font was only about the code tags :)