# Invalid location of <script> tag within a HTML <pre> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am going through the example given in ***JavaScript The Complete Reference 3rd Edition***.

The ***O/P*** can be seen [here](http://www.javascriptref.com/3ed/ch3/whitespacestrings.html), given by the author.

```
            <body> 
            <h1>Standard Whitespace Handling</h1> 

            <script>
            // STRINGS AND (X)HTML
            document.write("Welcome to JavaScript strings.\n");
            document.write("This example illustrates nested quotes 'like this.'\n");        
            document.write("Note how newlines (\\n's) and ");
            document.write("escape sequences are used.\n");
            document.write("You might wonder, \"Will this nested quoting work?\"");
            document.write(" It will.\n");
            document.write("Here's an example of some formatted data:\n\n");
            document.write("\tCode\tValue\n");
            document.write("\t\\n\tnewline\n");
            document.write("\t\\\\\tbackslash\n");
            document.write("\t\\\"\tdouble quote\n\n");
            </script>   

            <h1>Preserved Whitespace</h1> 
            <pre>
            <script>           // in Eclipse IDE, at this line invalid location of tag(script)                                             
            // STRINGS AND (X)HTML
            document.write("Welcome to JavaScript strings.\n");
            document.write("This example illustrates nested quotes 'like this.'\n");        
            document.write("Note how newlines (\\n's) and ");
            document.write("escape sequences are used.\n");
            document.write("You might wonder, \"Will this nested quoting work?\"");
            document.write(" It will.\n");
            document.write("Here's an example of some formatted data:\n\n");
            document.write("\tCode\tValue\n");
            document.write("\t\\n\tnewline\n");
            document.write("\t\\\\\tbackslash\n");
            document.write("\t\\\"\tdouble quote\n\n");
            </script>   
            </pre>
            </body>
```

(X)HTML automatically “collapses” ***multiple whitespace characters*** down to ***one whitespace***. So, for example, including multiple consecutive tabs in your HTML shows up as only one space character. In this example, the ***pre tag*** is used to tell the browser that the 
***text is preformatted and that it should not collapse the white space inside of it***. Similarly, we could use the ***CSS white-space property*** to modify standard ***white space handling***. Using ***pre*** allows the tabs in the example to be displayed correctly in the output.

So, how to get rid of this warning and do i really need to have a concern for this? I think i am missing something as i have the intuition of the authors not being wrong?

Comment: That book is 11 years old. I'm surprised it hasn't fossilized yet. Find yourself a newer reference that doesn't use `document.write()`. No sensible JS developer would write code like this nowadays. This is a non-issue.

Comment: And how would they write it? I mean to demonstrate 'hello world' example.

Comment: @jonasnas One way would be to create a `div` with an ID in the HTML and add an ID to the `pre` element, use script to build up strings using a variable and string concatenation, and then assign the string to the page elements using `getElementById()` and `.innerHTML`. I don't think you're going to find a respectable JS intro book written in the last 5 years that uses `document.write()` to create page content (with the possible exception of writing content to child windows).

Comment: @JLRishe: I have updated the eBook info which i have.

Comment: @JLRishe personally I don't mind using document.write in 'hello world' examples. Like in this case the topic of the book is about pre tag and not best practices of js. P.S. Even in 'definitive guide' book it mentions that using dom functions is better approach (like you suggest) but there are examples in the same book where author is using document.write('some tag') just to demonstrate some behaviour of other features book talks about

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong in having `script` inside `pre` tag. It is just Eclipse IDE validation issue. If you use this html in the browser everything works fine and no warnings are displayed.

Also, if you wanted to show script tag as 'text content' inside pre tag, then have a look at this question: [script in pre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882167/using-pre-and-code-tags-to-display-a-javascript-script)