# CSS white-space: no wrap, no horizontal scrollbar and maintain white-space when copied

Tags: css, whitespace

I'm trying to achieve a combination of three goals...

1. Determine if I should use `<code><pre>...</pre></code>` or `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`?
2. Make code not wrap, not create horizontal scrollbars and not overflow any parent element.
3. Ensure that when a visitor copies code that the white-space is maintained when they paste it in to any (competent) editor.

So far I've had the most luck with `white-space: pre-wrap;` however I do *not* want the text to wrap. If they're interested enough they'll copy-paste it for themselves. While I do not want it to wrap I also do not want it to make the element overflow outside of any parent element and I don't want the text to appear outside of it's direct parent element.

I'd be *okay* with a horizontal scrollbar for the code itself (`pre` or `code` element, whichever) though I'd generally prefer not to.

Just in case it's relevant I don't use any CSS frameworks or the likes, I only do a basic reset...

```
* {border: 0px; margin: 0px; outline: none; padding: 0px; }
```

I test in Firefox, then Chrome, then (actual) Opera and then maybe IE if I have sanity to spare. Thoughts please?

Comment: Could you please make an example of what you mean? here is a simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/A2zhH/1/ with scrollbars. You may also hide the overflow to have no scrollbar, but copyable content. Also this is a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742907/why-does-html5-recommend-putting-the-code-element-inside-pre

Comment: 1) is easy; since code elements can't contain pre elements, you put the code inside the pre. But what about 2)? What exactly should happen to lines that are too long?

Comment: Anyway, +1 for "(actual) Opera".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working to an accuracy of about 99.8% of the time using the following...

**XHTML**

```
<pre><code>/* Code here. */</code></pre>
```

**CSS**

```
pre {white-space: pre; width: 75vmax;}
```

Answer (score 0):

On number 2 and 3: Hopefully I haven't misunderstood your question--I got what I understood your goal to be working easily by by adding a fixed width and overflow:hidden to the css class.

On 1: it's working with `<pre (outer)><code (inner)>` so... hey.

http://jsfiddle.net/A2zhH/2/

FYI, `border: gray;` isn't doing anything. You need to use the format `border:1px gray solid;`

Answer (score 0):

Goal 1 is simple: `code` inside `pre` is valid, `pre` inside `code` is not. On the other hand, `pre` is what matters here. You can use `code` inside it as a matter of principle if the content is computer code.

Goal 2 is self-contradictory as such, unless you are referring to an idea of reducing font size so that everything fits. More realistically, with regard to the statement that it is okay to have a horizontal scroll bar for the code block, use just

```
pre { width: 100%; overflow: auto }
```

This causes a horizontal scroll bar to appear for the block, instead of overflowing the content.

Goal 3 is achieved when you use normal spaces. What is copied contains spaces, and what happens to them after paste depends on the software.