# How are nested tags in html translated by web browsers and how does order of nesting tags in matter?

Tags: html, pre

In html suppose I have two tags in hand `<code>` and `<pre>` and I want to write preformatted code then does the ordering of these tags matter? E.g. Are the following equivalent?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Code example:</p>
<pre><code>var person = {
firstName:"John2",
lastName:"Doe"
}</code></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I nest `<pre>` inside the `<code>` tag,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Code example:</p>
<code><pre>var person = {
firstName:"John2",
lastName:"Doe"
}</pre></code>

</body>
</html>
```

Would there be any technical difference between the above two approaches?

Addendum: I also don't understand how is the html code being translated here. In the first version The text inside the code tags should be translated into something which doesn't retain extra white spaces and line-breaks so the pre tags should see the output of code tags and should not render extra white spaces and line breaks.

And in the second case the output of pre tags should be given to code tags. Now the code tags will see the preserved extra white spaces and line breaks but the output of code tags should not retain them because that is what the code tag does; it gives up extra white spaces and line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [html elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html) in general, there are 2 major groups, [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements), for example

> <span> **<code>** <a> <img> <b>

and [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

> <div> **<pre>** <p> <h1> <ul>

To be nested [valid](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Validating_your_HTML), a block element can contain

- an inline element
- a block element

and an inline element can contain

- an inline element

There are exceptions, though I will not bring them up here.

Also, if one would put a block element inside an inline, it will often still show the same output.
Why? ... Most browsers will try to *interpret* what one did and try to "fix it and make it work anyway".

So to answer your question

> does the ordering of these tags matter?

Yes, in general, block elements are not allowed inside inline elements, but there can be other reasons and exceptions as well.

---

Regarding your question (comment)

> Which is translated first? The code inside <code> or the <pre> tags are given higher priority?

Short answer, the inner element's *property*, when set, either explicit or predefined, overrides the outer element's equal property.

So in your case, the `pre` element's [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property is set, as default, to `white-space: pre` and as the `white-space` property is [inherited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance) by default, the `code` uses that value, hence the output looks the same as for the `pre` element.

But if we were to explicit set the `white-space` property on the `code` element, it will behave as you might expect, with no line breaks etc.

```css
#reset code {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Example: inheritence of property</p>
  <pre>
    <code>
    var person = {
firstName:"John2",
lastName:"Doe"
}  
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="reset">
  <p>Example: explicit set property</p>
  <pre>
    <code>
    var person = {
firstName:"John2",
lastName:"Doe"
}  
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: So I understand it as that the inner element _takes_, that is inherits, the property of its parent element. In your code `<pre>` inherits the property of `<div>`.

Comment: But if it is so then in `<code><pre> xyz </pre></code>` the _pre_ should inherit the property of _code_ and hence line breaks and extra white spaces should not be rendered. But that doesn't happen.

Comment: @user31782 No, because in this case the `pre` tag itself is defined with the white-space property set, and as such does not inherit. Similar is if you would put a `div` inside a `span` the `div` is still a block and will continue behave as one.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. I guess some elements do not inherit their parent element's property.

Comment: @user31782 Right, some elements have a predefined behavior and need to be explicit overridden to change.

Comment: I am not getting your this statement,"_Short answer, the inner element's property, when set, either explicit or inherited, **overrides the outer element's equal property**._" Do you mean the outer element takes the inner element's property?

Comment: @user31782 Nope, the other way around.

Comment: @user31782 updated my answer a little, made a mistake writing _either explicit or inherited_, should be _either explicit or predefined_

Comment: I think I need to read that MDN tutorial in detail. Neither I know html well nor English. I'll reply you later.

Comment: As far as I know _override_ means _invalidate_ something. The inner element's property override the outer element's mean the outer element's property is no longer valid so doesn't it mean that the inner element has higher priority and hence in <pre><code>xyz</code></pre> the property of _code_ should override the property of _pre_?

Comment: @user31782  Override means _extend or overlap_. It is not the element that has higher priority, it is its properties, and as such they can be explicit set, intherited or predefined. If the outer elements has a predefined property and the inner element is not explicit set, then the property of the outer will rule unless the inner has that very same property predefined.

Answer (score 2):

> does the ordering of these tags matter? E.g. Are the following
>   equivalent?

Although the output will be equivalent both ways, the ordering *does* matter when writing valid and semantic html5 code

According to the [html5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element) regarding the `<pre>` element:

> Contexts in which this element can be used: Where **flow content** is
>   expected.

whereas regarding [the `<code>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element):

> Contexts in which this element can be used: Where **phrasing content** is
>   expected.

(Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1)))

> Would there be any technical difference between the above two
>   approaches?

Yes. Nesting the pre element within the code element isn't valid html5 (using [this validator](https://html5.validator.nu/)) and produces the error:

> Error: Element pre not allowed as child of element code in this
>   context.

Comment: Is it valid in older versions of html?

Comment: What I don't get is in `<pre>
    <code>something  something</code>
</pre>` The text inside code tags is translated into something which doesn't contain white spaces and line breaks then how does the pre tags preserve the white spaces and line breaks?

Comment: Why does html code have to follow the content model? That is what is it's benefit? If the invalid code can be rendered properly then why is it called invalid?

Answer (score 1):

About your comment

> What I don't get is in <pre><code>something something</code></pre>
>   The text inside code tags is translated into something which doesn't
>   contain white spaces and line breaks then how does the pre tags
>   preserve the white spaces and line breaks?

In addition to @Danield's great explanation, here's a sample showing the `pre` tag do preserve white spaces and line breaks.

```html
<div>
  <p>PRE/CODE example:</p>
  <pre>
    <code>
    var person = {
firstName:"John2",
lastName:"Doe"
}  
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

More to read:

- [What is difference between <pre> and <code> HTML Tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065677/what-is-difference-between-pre-and-code-html-tag)
- [<code> vs <pre> vs <samp> for inline and block code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets)
- [Why does HTML5 recommend putting the code element inside pre?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742907/why-does-html5-recommend-putting-the-code-element-inside-pre)

Comment: But I still don't understand how `<pre>` preserves the line-breaks of the translated code of `<code>` tags.

Comment: @user31782 The `code` tag doesn't _undo_ what the `pre` tag does. Does that make sense?

Comment: Which is translated first? The code inside `<code>` or the `<pre>` tags are given higher priority?

Comment: @user31782 I haven't read the specs, but as you can see in the sample, when `pre` is present, `code` doesn't change or undo anything, so `pre` tag obviously have a higher priority.

Comment: How does the web browser translate nested html tags and render them? I think `code` is designed to take care of `<pre>`. Whenever there will be `<pre>` the code tag will preserve line breaks.

Comment: @user31782 If you read the last (3:rd) link in my answer, it might help you understand the difference between the two

Comment: In the 3rd link they are doing something else. They are comparing `<pre><code>xyz</pre></code>` with `<code class="auto-markup">xyz</code>`. I want to know how things work on the inside. How are nested tags dealt with by the web browser.

Comment: @user31782 Do you mean nested elements in general?

Comment: Yes, both in general and for this specific case in particular.

Comment: @user31782 I added a personal answer as well, to be more general in what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow uses it like this for multiple lines of code:

```
<pre>
    <code>something</code>
</pre>
```

The code tag uses a fixed width font, while the pre tag additionally preserves white space and line breaks. The code tag represents computer code, while the pre tag could contain basically anything (computer code in code tags but also some nice formatted piece of text or some ASCII picture etc.).

Comment: I've edited the question to be more descriptive. Could you explain it.